# Solving an eigenvalue problem

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I am computing the eigenvalues of Laplacian-type operator on the unit square $\Omega = [0, 1]^2$

Consider the eigenvalue problem on the unit square $\Omega$, $$-L u = \lambda u$$ where $$L = e^{2y} \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2} {\partial y^2} - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

with the Dirichlet boundary condition $u = 0$ at $\partial \Omega$.

I have attempted the following.

First I  have specified the Laplacian

```
ℒ = Exp[2 y]*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] +  D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] -  D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] &;
```

Then I have specified the Dirichlet boundary condition

```
ℬ = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True];
```

Computed the five smallest eigenvalues in the unit square.

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{ℒ, ℬ}, 
   u[x, y], {x, 0, 1},{y, 0, 1},  5];
```

Then I have inspected the eigenvalues

```
vals
```

But I am facing difficulties as it gives error.

```
NDEigensystem:The dependent variables specification(​{u[x,y]}) does not match the differential operator dependent variables
```

[image]

[image]

Please help me.

Thanking in advanced.

Comment: What errors do you get? At which point?

Comment: I have edited the question and have added the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three modifications: add dependence on $x$ and $y$ (add `[x_,y_]` to the definitions and `[x,y]` to where the script letters are referenced), remove the `&` (this defines ℒ as an unnamed function which shouldn't be) and you probably mean `{y,0,1}`.

```
Clear@ℒ
Clear@ℬ
ℒ[x_,y_]=Exp[2y]*D[u[x,y],{x,2}]+D[u[x,y],{y,2}]-D[u[x,y],{y,1}];
ℬ[x_,y_]=DirichletCondition[u[x,y]==0.,True];
{vals,funs}=NDEigensystem[{ℒ[x,y],ℬ[x,y]},u[x,y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},5];
vals
```